# Form is replacing my variable in Symfony 4

Tags: forms, variables, controller, twig, symfony4

I want to update the list of users of an Entity called SAI, but after submiting the form, I lose the information of the SAI I want to update and it gets replaced with the SAI returned by the form.

I tried to explain what happens with comentaries in the following code:

**EdditSAIController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit_sai/{id}/", name="edit_sai", requirements={"page"="\d+"}))
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editSAI(Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $idSAI = $request->attributes->get('id_sai'); //Get the ID of the SAI from the link
    $sai = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SAI::class)->find($idSAI); //Find the SAI in the database
    $oldUsers = $sai->getUsers(); //Get the users of the SAI
    $form = $this->createForm(SAIType::class,$sai); //Create the form, which includes a serial number and a list of users that you can modify, by adding or removing users
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        $newSAI = $form->getData(); //Get the data of the new SAI
        $sai->setSerialNumber($newSAI->getSerialNumber()); //Update the serial number
        $usersToAdd = $newSAI->getUsers();

        //If the old users are not in the list of users of the SAI returned by the form, it means that they got removed and
        //I have to remove them from the current SAI
        //(this is where the problem starts, since $oldUsers now contains the same users as the $newSAI, and I don't know why)
        //(and of course both of these loops won't work because $oldUsers and $usersToAdd contain the same data)
        foreach($oldUsers as $oldUser){
            if (!$usersToAdd->contains($oldUser)){
                $sai->deleteUser($oldUser);
            }
        }

        //Add the new users to the current SAI
        foreach($usersToAdd as $newUser){
            $sai->addUser($newUser);
        }

        //Update SAI
        $entityManager->persist($sai);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('sais');
    }

    return $this->render('management/edit_sai.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**edit_sai.html.twig**

```
{%  extends 'home/index.html.twig' %}

{%  block body %}

<div class="main">
    <h1>Editar SAI</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="formUsers">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>

{%  endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script> $('select[data-select="true"]').select2({}); </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong and what should I do to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Try this, keep using $sai variable, remove from-> getData

Comment: Doing that doesn't help because I continue having the same problem: $oldUsers and $newUsers are equal. It's a many to many relationship so I can't just call persist and flush, I have to use the add and delete methods of User and SAI entities.

Comment: I have managed to add users, but not to remove them.
To add, what I do is get the users from the form, delete all of them from the SAI and then add them again.
Why this doesn't work for removing? Because If I create the form for a SAI with users 1 and 2. And let's say I remove the user 2 in the form. When I get the users from the form, I have only user 1, and then I remove it and insert it again, but the problem is that user 2 it's still there in the "real" SAI and it wasn't removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find what was wrong.
As Deniz Aktürk said in a comment, it was enough to use:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    //Update SAI
    $entityManager->persist($sai);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

But the problem was my functions names:
 - In User.php class I had delteSAI() instead of removeSAI().
 - In SAI.php class I had deleteUser() instead of removeUser().

I also added *cascade={"persist", "remove"}* in both classes:

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SAI", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_sais")
 */
private $sais;
```

**SAI.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="sais", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $users;
```

I had no idea that Symfony4 it's so strict about naming functions. I hope this will help someone.